# is ajax a backend technology to fetch data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, frontend, backend

I want to know if ajax is a backend technology to fetch data or it's only considered as a frontend technology. I've searched for it in google but did not get any clear and straight answer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest. Go through the MDN if you understand the mechanism you will have a clear answer

Comment: "ajax" is just a term to refer to the requests and responses that transfer data over HTTP, without requiring a whole new page to be downloaded. Years ago, when the term was introduced, this wasn't so common and it deserved a special definition. Nowadays we can say that almost any request on the web is ajax

Comment: @CristianTraìna — There's no requirement for Ajax to involve JSON. Heck, there's no requirement for Ajax to involve XML despite that being what the X in the name stands for.

Comment: @Quentin you are right, I improved the comment

Comment: Most requests aren't Ajax either. Requests for whole pages are not. Requests for images are not. Requests for most JS programs are not. Requests for CSS are not. Downloads are now. Etc.

Comment: Look at MDN: [Glossary](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/AJAX), [Guide](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is not a technology.

It is terminology given to the act using JavaScript embedded in a webpage (client-side code) to make an HTTP request (to a backend) and processing the response without leaving the page.